# Moving Win 10 installation between computers which have license

Tags: windows-10, license

I have two laptops. Each has its own valid OEM license of Win 10 (Home, but I will have to verify that). Laptop A is brand new, laptop B is my current work laptop.

(How) Can I move the Win 10 installation from laptop B to Laptop A?

Notice that I don't want to move the license, just the installation (to avoid reinstalling everything). In the end, I want the license on laptop B to be available to whoever will 'inherit' this laptop, and I will keep using the license of Laptop A with my original installation.

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution as simple as

1. Do some magic on Laptop B to mark its license as unused
2. Move my HDD from Laptop B to Laptop A
3. Do some magic on Laptop A to active the installation using its license, (re)install drivers and live happily ever after

Possible duplicates: https://superuser.com/a/736093 (for win 7)

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you want Laptop A to be configured identically to what Laptop B is. You could try transferring the physical drive from B to A and A to B, however one will maintain is base installation, you may run into some driver issues depending on the differences in hardware on the devices. Alternatively you could try cloning the drives, but you likely would run into issues with the licensing.

The easiest, albeit most time consuming way, would be to configure the new laptop manually. Transfer all your required files from the old laptop to a thumb drive or other external storage device and then begin re-installing required programs.