# Moving Windows 7 x64 Pro to a new machine

Tags: windows-7, migration, windows-7-backup, windows-7-restore

I have a Laptop running W7 x64 Pro, from a student license. 
I plan to install the same W7 x64 Pro on a new Desktop machine, using the same license.

Now, in order to copy all my applications and settings/data to the new machine, is it a feasible and good idea to just make an image of the Laptop machine using the Windows 7 backup regime and to restore that image on the freshly installed Deskop W7?

Thanks!
Winston

Comment: Try this, follow my suggestion in link to generalize the installation, except do not select shutdown, select "quit" once it is done generalizing, make a system image. Transfer this image to the new hard drive, boot up and enter your key and install drivers....see "edit 1"  section....http://superuser.com/a/412525/40928

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is it a feasible and good idea to just make an IMAGE of the Laptop`

Feasible: yes.
A good idea: no.

Your desktop will have different hardware and will require different drivers. While you can take an image of the old laptop, you still will have to do some installing on the new desktop. And it will likely involve sysprep or other software to remove parts from the laptop before you image it.

It will work, but you will end with all old software (good) and all old cruft (bad).

Personally I would make a clean install on the new desktop. Run all windows updates. 
Then make a backup of that (for future emergency use). Next would be installation and updating of anti virus software and the copying of old files from the laptop. (Either via a network or by temporarily putting the laptop disk in an external 2½ case).

However if you go for the image solution, read up on `sysprep generalise`.

Comment: This will also likely trigger a re-activation from Microsoft, so make sure you have your key handy.  And remember that legally you can no longer use that key on your laptop.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer. It makes sense. I will consider sysprep, also the answer by Moab in his other post.